# Flutter In App Purchase Handle user cancel in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm making In App Purchase to my app with `in_app_purchase: ^0.3.5+1`.
With android, I got detailed error message like `BillingResponse.userCanceled`, `BillingResponse.itemAlreadyOwned`.
With those Message, I can handle errors by case with proper actions.

But in IOS, I'm confused how to know User cancel the purchase.
When I cancel purchase in IOS, It's just say `SKErrorDomain`.
How can I specify When user cancel purchase in IOS?

Comment: You need to cast the error to `SKError` and then check the [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code)

Comment: Thanks. I find out I can get SKError through ```purchaseDetails.skPaymentTransaction.error.code``` but Is there any document that explain what the error code is?

Comment: The link in my previous comment gives you the values and their meanings